# Magento 2 Getting js errors on home page and not only TypeError: $.widget is not a function, TypeError: $.ui is undefined

Tags: magento2

I am getting these errors on the console.

```
TypeError: $.widget is not a function
TypeError: $.ui is undefined
```

I thought maybe it's something wrong with the order of the js files are loading on the head section so this is how the head part is loading the files

`

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/requirejs-config.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/jquery.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/lightslider.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  data-requiremodule="jquery" src="http://eshop.xxx.gr/pub/static/frontend/Sm/revo/en_US/js/yttheme.js"></script>
```

Also When Click to open Quick View i get a

```
TypeError: $(...).elevateZoom is not a function
```

Despite of the file being loaded on the head section

Comment: did you get any solution for this bug? I am facing same problem while adding any product to compare list or add to cart. Sometimes js loading properly, but sometimes getting error like this in console. If you got any suggestion or solution then post here.